# Angular 7 installing and using Drag n Drop without Material

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 7 for a project and I want to use the Drag n Drop feature.

Reading the documentation it's forcing me to install Angular Material which is something that I don't want to install or use.

Having said that what are my option here?

Can I not install the drag n drop feature without installing Angular Material?

If so, what's my best alternative?

Comment: This is solid https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula

Answer (score 12):

```
npm install --save @angular/cdk
```

**Html**

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="list2" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="firstList" #secondList="cdkDropList" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div *ngFor="let item of list2" class="pop" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="list1" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="secondList" #firstList="cdkDropList" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div *ngFor="let item of list1" class="pop" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**script** Appmodule

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
@NgModule({
imports: [
    SharedModule,
    DragDropModule
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent       
],
 providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Appcomponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem } from 
'@angular/cdk/drag-drop'

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })

 export class AppComponent {
 constructor() { }

 list1 = [
    "item 1",
    "item 2",
    "item 3",
    "item 4",
    "item 5"
 ];

 list2 = [
    "item 6",
    "item 7",
    "item 8",
    "item 9",
    "item 10"
 ];

 drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer !== event.container) {
    transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex)
    } else {
    moveItemInArray(this.list1, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try install cdk:
`npm install --save @angular/cdk`
And use CDK Drag Drop Module, [official doc](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api)